# Search Netflix for results as an intersection of two categories (audio language, subtitles)

Tags: netflix, subtitles

I want to find the collection of programmes available on Netflix (in Japan, but I think the answer will probably be the same for any region) which are returned for two separate searches - in my case, those programmes with English subtitles in the category Japanese TV, or Japanese films, in query style notation: `Select Movie Where Subtitle='English' AND (Category='Japanese TV' OR 'Japanese Films')`

Japanese audio with English subtitles would also be fine, but leads to a large number of American/English programmes dubbed in Japanese.

Both of these searches are possible in Netflix (Japanese TV/Film are dropdown categories, subtitles can be found with `/browse/subtitle/en`.

Is it possible to find the results which occur in both?

I tried to parse the source returned by Chrome when I open these pages, and managed to get a list of titles using `grep` and `sed` in a VM, but these are limited by the length to which you scroll down (to load more programmes) before copy-pasting the source into a text editor. It seems quite a fragile method, and additionally is very time consuming when one of the categories has a lot of entries (or worse, if both do...)

Comment: User story (Germany): Yesterday I moused over a program that had the categories `LGBTQ`, `Sci-Fi`, and one other category that I can't remember. Today I want to find that show, but I can't remember the name. This search feature could enable me to find it.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a feature that Netflix provides. BUT: It's a nice project idea for a web crawler aggregation side. I will think about it and maybe try to implement it.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer [tag:filter] is a meta-tag as it can't be used alone on this site. Generally meta-tags should not be used. Please checkout [Let's clean up some meta tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2696/88163) and [In the context of Web Applications, which are the tags that are not specific to a web application that are not meta-tags?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3986/88163)

Comment: @Rubén Thanks for educating me. Why is it still available as a tag then? I thought it had been cleaned up?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer Because it wasn't burninated **and** blacklisted.